# Azure DevOps yaml restore packages to specific directory

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

I have a monorepo with several solutions and trying to configure NuGet yaml to restore to the root directory.
By defalut `task: NuGetCommand@2` restores only in the `.sln` file directory but this will not work for me.

The UI pipelines version has parameter `Folder` which allows setting a path for packages path.

Is there any parameter for the yaml version?

I tried to set an environment variable - but it's doesn't work.

The yaml code fragment is:

```
- name: NUGET_PACKAGES
  value: $(build.SourcesDirectory)/

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Nuget Restore '
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    nugetConfigPath: 'packages.config'
    verbosityRestore: 'Normal'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) you can use the parameter `restoreDirectory`:

> Specifies the folder in which packages are installed. If no folder is
>   specified, packages are restored into a packages/ folder alongside the
>   selected solution, packages.config, or project.json.